# Decipher my match against mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

It works when I'm not also trying to include score. But of course this is important for ordering of search results. This doesn't work:

```
SELECT * from
          ( SELECT distinct ts.users_user_id from subjects s
          JOIN teachers_subjects ts ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id, MATCH  (s.subject_en_name) AGAINST ('math') AS score 
          WHERE MATCH (s.subject_en_name) AGAINST ("math") ) qualified
          JOIN users u ON qualified.users_user_id = u.user_id
          JOIN users_teachers ut ON qualified.users_user_id = ut.user_id
          JOIN teachers_subjects ts2 ON qualified.users_user_id = ts2.users_user_id
          JOIN subjects s2 ON ts2.subject_id = s2.subject_id
```

This works, but doesn't include the score of each row:

```
SELECT * from
          ( SELECT distinct ts.users_user_id from subjects s
          JOIN teachers_subjects ts ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id 
          WHERE MATCH (s.subject_en_name) AGAINST ("math") ) qualified
          JOIN users u ON qualified.users_user_id = u.user_id
          JOIN users_teachers ut ON qualified.users_user_id = ut.user_id
          JOIN teachers_subjects ts2 ON qualified.users_user_id = ts2.users_user_id
          JOIN subjects s2 ON ts2.subject_id = s2.subject_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `score` should be part of `SELECT` not `FROM` clause. Try it this way

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ts.users_user_id, 
         MATCH (s.subject_en_name) AGAINST ('math') AS score 
    FROM subjects s JOIN teachers_subjects ts 
      ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id
   WHERE MATCH (s.subject_en_name) AGAINST ('math')
) q JOIN users u 
    ON q.users_user_id = u.user_id JOIN users_teachers ut 
    ON q.users_user_id = ut.user_id JOIN teachers_subjects ts2 
    ON q.users_user_id = ts2.users_user_id JOIN subjects s2 
    ON ts2.subject_id = s2.subject_id
 ORDER BY q.score DESC
```

Comment: Did it help after all?